# Updated Google Analytics breaks website

Tags: google-analytics

I uninstalled the [Google Analytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module and installed a newer version for Drupal 8. Now the website crashes with this exception error.

> Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: "Route "view.google_analytics_summary.page_1" does not exist." at /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php line 208

I have no idea how to fix this since I can't log in on the site. I also can't use Drush because the site is on a ECS server that doesn't give me access to the terminal.

Comment: If you can't use Drush you can use rebuild.php.

Comment: It's just rerouting to the home page with the same message. Not sure why it's not working. I've cleared the cache tables from the database and it still has the same issue.

Comment: Did you run rebuild.php? It's more powerful than clearing some cache tables in the database. If this doesn't help you have a problem with the uninstall routines in the module you've removed. Might be a beta version not supposed to be used in production. It deleted the view google_analytics_summary but left a reference to this view. I would use a local copy of the site and then investigate the code base and the exported config for the missing route name.

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/prevent-cache-clear.html#s-using-the-rebuild-script

Comment: If you upgraded a module that broke the site and didn't run the database updates, just revert back to the previous version of the module.

Comment: The OP uninstalled the old module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running update.php to force the cache to rebuild correctly. There wasn't an analytics update but I got luck there was another update and when it finished running it recompiled the code and fixed the issue.